# Java lang runtime exception or jar file does not exist error

Tags: hadoop, mapreduce, pagerank

I am trying to run simple pagerank labtask on my hadoop 3.3.6 installed on ubuntu virtual box but it is giving this error while all my commands are true and my instructor just tole me to download hadoop again because we cant figure out this error Can anyone help?[terminal screenshot here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/voWuC.jpg) these are the command lines

```
hadoop jar Home/hadoop-3.3.6/share/hadoop/tools/lib/hadoop-streaming-3.3.6.jar -input /inputs7/input3.txt -output /inputs7/input3.txt -mapper mapper1.py -reducer reducer1.py -file /home/amina01/Documents/mapper1.py -file /home/amina01/Documents/mapper1.py
```

These are my commands I started from the beginning now It is giving even more newer ones

```
amina01@amina01-VirtualBox:~/Documents$ hdfs dfs -mkdir -p /user/amina01

amina01@amina01-VirtualBox:~/Documents$ hdfs dfs -put -f /home/amina01/Documents/input.txt

amina01@amina01-VirtualBox:~/Documents$ hdfs dfs -put -f /home/amina01/Documents/input.txt /user/amina01

amina01@amina01-VirtualBox:~/Documents$ hdfs dfs -mkdir -p /input/output

amina01@amina01-VirtualBox:~/Documents$ python3 driver.py /input/input.txt /input/output /home/amina01/Documents/mapper.py /home/amina01/Documents/reducer.py 5
```

and the error goes like

```
cp: `/input/input.txt': No such file or directory

2024-03-13 23:55:07,241 WARN streaming.StreamJob: -file option is deprecated, please use generic option -files instead.

packageJobJar: [/home/amina01/Documents/mapper.py, /home/amina01/Documents/reducer.py, /tmp/hadoop-unjar7254882529784803509/] [] /tmp/streamjob4354537991983504292.jar tmpDir=null

2024-03-13 23:55:08,512 INFO client.DefaultNoHARMFailoverProxyProvider: Connecting to ResourceManager at /0.0.0.0:8032

2024-03-13 23:55:08,885 INFO client.DefaultNoHARMFailoverProxyProvider: Connecting to ResourceManager at /0.0.0.0:8032

2024-03-13 23:55:09,195 INFO mapreduce.JobResourceUploader: Disabling Erasure Coding for path: /tmp/hadoop-yarn/staging/amina01/.staging/job_1710346569620_0001

2024-03-13 23:55:09,934 INFO mapred.FileInputFormat: Total input files to process : 0

2024-03-13 23:55:10,056 INFO mapreduce.JobSubmitter: number of splits:0

2024-03-13 23:55:10,352 INFO mapreduce.JobSubmitter: Submitting tokens for job: job_1710346569620_0001

2024-03-13 23:55:10,353 INFO mapreduce.JobSubmitter: Executing with tokens: []

2024-03-13 23:55:10,756 INFO conf.Configuration: resource-types.xml not found

2024-03-13 23:55:10,757 INFO resource.ResourceUtils: Unable to find 'resource-types.xml'.

2024-03-13 23:55:11,160 INFO impl.YarnClientImpl: Submitted application application_1710346569620_0001

2024-03-13 23:55:11,300 INFO mapreduce.Job: The url to track the job: http://amina01-VirtualBox:8088/proxy/application_1710346569620_0001/

2024-03-13 23:55:11,306 INFO mapreduce.Job: Running job: job_1710346569620_0001

2024-03-13 23:55:21,526 INFO mapreduce.Job: Job job_1710346569620_0001 running in uber mode : false

2024-03-13 23:55:21,530 INFO mapreduce.Job:  map 0% reduce 0%

2024-03-13 23:55:27,754 INFO mapreduce.Job: Task Id : attempt_1710346569620_0001_r_000000_0, Status : FAILED

Error: java.lang.RuntimeException: PipeMapRed.waitOutputThreads(): subprocess failed with code 1
 at org.apache.hadoop.streaming.PipeMapRed.waitOutputThreads(PipeMapRed.java:326)

    at org.apache.hadoop.streaming.PipeMapRed.mapRedFinished(PipeMapRed.java:539)

    at org.apache.hadoop.streaming.PipeReducer.close(PipeReducer.java:134)

    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.ReduceTask.runOldReducer(ReduceTask.java:454)

    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.ReduceTask.run(ReduceTask.java:393)

    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.YarnChild$2.run(YarnChild.java:178)

    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)

    at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:422)

    at org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.doAs(UserGroupInformation.java:1899)

    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.YarnChild.main(YarnChild.java:172)



2024-03-13 23:55:32,828 INFO mapreduce.Job: Task Id : attempt_1710346569620_0001_r_000000_1, Status : FAILED

Error: java.lang.RuntimeException: PipeMapRed.waitOutputThreads(): subprocess failed with code 1

    at org.apache.hadoop.streaming.PipeMapRed.waitOutputThreads(PipeMapRed.java:326)

    at org.apache.hadoop.streaming.PipeMapRed.mapRedFinished(PipeMapRed.java:539)

    at org.apache.hadoop.streaming.PipeReducer.close(PipeReducer.java:134)

    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.ReduceTask.runOldReducer(ReduceTask.java:454)

    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.ReduceTask.run(ReduceTask.java:393)

    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.YarnChild$2.run(YarnChild.java:178)

    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)

    at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:422)

    at org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.doAs(UserGroupInformation.java:1899)

    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.YarnChild.main(YarnChild.java:172)



2024-03-13 23:55:38,895 INFO mapreduce.Job: Task Id : attempt_1710346569620_0001_r_000000_2, Status : FAILED

Error: java.lang.RuntimeException: PipeMapRed.waitOutputThreads(): subprocess failed with code 1

    at org.apache.hadoop.streaming.PipeMapRed.waitOutputThreads(PipeMapRed.java:326)

    at org.apache.hadoop.streaming.PipeMapRed.mapRedFinished(PipeMapRed.java:539)

    at org.apache.hadoop.streaming.PipeReducer.close(PipeReducer.java:134)

    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.ReduceTask.runOldReducer(ReduceTask.java:454)

    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.ReduceTask.run(ReduceTask.java:393)

    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.YarnChild$2.run(YarnChild.java:178)

    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)

    at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:422)

    at org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.doAs(UserGroupInformation.java:1899)

    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.YarnChild.main(YarnChild.java:172)



2024-03-13 23:55:44,938 INFO mapreduce.Job:  map 0% reduce 100%

2024-03-13 23:55:46,023 INFO mapreduce.Job: Job job_1710346569620_0001 failed with state FAILED due to: Task failed task_1710346569620_0001_r_000000

Job failed as tasks failed. failedMaps:0 failedReduces:1 killedMaps:0 killedReduces: 0



2024-03-13 23:55:46,200 INFO mapreduce.Job: Counters: 7

    Job Counters 

        Failed reduce tasks=4

        Launched reduce tasks=4

        Total time spent by all maps in occupied slots (ms)=0

        Total time spent by all reduces in occupied slots (ms)=12214

        Total time spent by all reduce tasks (ms)=12214

        Total vcore-milliseconds taken by all reduce tasks=12214

        Total megabyte-milliseconds taken by all reduce tasks=12507136

2024-03-13 23:55:46,200 ERROR streaming.StreamJob: Job not successful!

Streaming Command Failed!
```

Comment: 1) Please provide the code and error as text, not an image 2) Your `-input` and `-output` are the same arguments 3) You have not added `reducer1.py` as a file argument, so "file does not exist" seems like a reasonable error message

Comment: edited the question to include but couldnt include the whole error

Comment: Without seeing `driver.py`, `mapper.py`, etc, we cannot know why your code might be failing, but `cp: /input/input.txt': No such file or directory` means you have no local file by that name, the error is not referring to HDFS

Comment: Now I am downloading hadoop again but can I make sure how to delete this version first I ran the commands from various sources but couldnt completely delete it becaue it is still in my home folder

Comment: amina01@amina01-VirtualBox:~/Downloads$ sudo apt-get remove hadoop

Reading package lists... Done

Building dependency tree... Done

Reading state information... Done

E: Unable to locate package hadoop

Comment: hadoop is not part of apt repos, just download from the official website; but that will not fix the error about invalid command arguments given to your script... Also, in your logs, says `The url to track the job`, with an address you can get the actual error message from Hadoop Streaming jobs